# Can you see vimeo upload progress in Premiere CC?

Tags: premiere, adobe, cc, vimeo

I'm trying to use Adobe Premiere CC's built-in Vimeo uploader.
I saw a progress bar as the h264 file was being encoded... I can't see any way of telling how long the upload is going to take... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no such thing. Vimeo will show you a gauge as soon as it starts processing your video.